# asp.net mvc code first deployment

Tags: asp.net, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to publish an asp.net mvc 5 code-first application using VS2015. After updating my azure sdk, I cannot see the option to deploy to azure.

[image]

Comment: "More Options"....I wonder what's there?

Comment: The only option under the "More Options" is "Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines"

Comment: What's the version of visual studio and [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/#install) you installed? I'm using Azure SDK 2.9, I can see all options when I try to publish my project, you can try to upgrade the SDK to 2.9 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I simply resolved it by uninstalling VS and reinstalling it again. All the problems went away and I was able to publish the app to azure without any challenge. Am pretty sure a VS repair could have resolved the issue also.